# Unable to click on a Radio button using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="radioTypeTable" class="radioTable">
      <tbody><tr id="transactionType">    
       
         
          <td align="left" style="width:12px;"><input type="radio" name="preliminaryApplication_TransactionType" tabindex="200" value="1" checked="checked" onclick="clearFSProgramsOnChangeOfTransType();resetDlrPreferredFs();changeTransactionType(this);" id="preliminaryApplication_TransactionType_1" class=""></td>
         <td align="left" class="transtypeLabel"><strong><label id="preliminaryApplication_TransactionType_1_label" for="preliminaryApplication_TransactionType_1">Option1</label></strong></td><td style="width:5%;">&nbsp;</td>

          <td align="left" style="width:12px;"><input type="radio" name="preliminaryApplication_TransactionType" tabindex="200" value="2" onclick="clearFSProgramsOnChangeOfTransType();resetDlrPreferredFs();changeTransactionType(this);" id="preliminaryApplication_TransactionType_2"></td>
         <td align="left" class="transtypeLabel"><strong><label id="preliminaryApplication_TransactionType_2_label" for="preliminaryApplication_TransactionType_2">Option2</label></strong></td><td style="width:5%;">&nbsp;</td>
  
      </tr>   
      <tr>
       <td align="left" colspan="10">

       </td>    
      </tr>          
     </tbody></table>
```

I have a page that contains multiple radio Buttons with a particular one Selected by default to begin with. While trying to click on any other Radio, it simply does not work and moves further without failing.
Things I have tried so far:

**Actions class "double click"**

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.doubleClick(element).perform();
```

**Actions class "moveToElement" and then click**

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
actions.click();
actions.build().perform();
```

**Javascript Executor click**

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Even tried in clicking in a while loop

Nothing worked so far. Everything else on the page before and after this button works without any issues. I have looked for any possible iFrames as well. I could see the button being turned blue while clicking on it. However, the click does not stick. I have also given sufficient wait both implicit and explicit to try as well. I have also checked if the button is visible or not. Any suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to click on a radio button in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307141/unable-to-click-on-a-radio-button-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Have gone thru that and given sufficient wait both implicit and explicit to try as well. Nothing worked so far.

Comment: Please share the page html and thrown exception (if any).

Comment: I have added the snippet of html page above. As I have mentioned, I don't get any exception.